# Informing activity class about action from service or thread class

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

From my service class, I am starting one thread. What would be the best way to inform activity if any action is taken by thread class? I want to inform my activity class that some action has been taken by thread. Question will be clear from below code

MyService class onCreate() method

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    if (downloadThread == null) {
        downloadThread = new DownloadThread(this);
        downloadThread.activateUserSession();
        downloadThread.start();
    }
}
```

My download thread

```
public void run()
{
    while (!isStopRequested) {
        if (isSessionActive && downloadNow) 
        {

            downloadNow = false;
            informActivity("Download Started");

            //do some loading work !!
            SystemClock.sleep(10000);

            informActivity("Download Finished");
        }

        SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Don't get into details when downloadNow is true, etc. I just need how do I inform my activity that download is started and download is finish. Something need to do with Handler. Can anybody let me know the BEST way to handle this situation.

Comment: Are you starting the Service with an Intent or binding to it? (You should be binding.)

Comment: I am starting my service from Application class by intent adn binding the service to my activity which I call MainActivity

Comment: I'm not sure about best solution but u can use handlers for your purpose.

Comment: Ya i know that, I have even added this in my question.But how to make use that handler in my service and/or service class to inform my activity regarding the event

Comment: Check this example[Bluetooth Chat](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/BluetoothChat.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you use `startActivity` from your background service. So in its simplest form you could have

```
String theEvent = "downloadStarted";
Intent intentForActivity = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intentForActivity.putExtra(THE_EVENT, theEvent);
startActivity(intentForActivity)
```

If your activity is already running (as you've described) then the entry point will be `onNewIntent`, and there you can pull out `THE_EVENT` and handle it case-by-case

```
onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String theEvent = intent.getExtra(THE_EVENT);
    if (theEvent.equals("downloadStarted") {
        // do your stuff
    } else if (theEvent.equals("downloadCompleted") {
        // do your other stuff 
    }
}
```

A `Handler` just allows you to queue things up for later without completely blocking your thread. In your case this might be helpful if you're talking about lots of concurrent downloads, but it shouldn't be necessary to get started.

Comment: Thanx scott for answer, but I have already started my application. My activity is in running mode. I can say that, suppose in that activity when I click a button, it check for few condition and then from service start DownloadThread. So when download starts I want to inform my activity that downloading is start, and when finished inform accordingly.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the name: it's called `startActivity`, but it will serve the function of sending a message to a running activity. Then instead of `onCreate`, the activity will execute a function called `onNewIntent`.

Comment: Okk, got your point. Still I don't understand sending the intent to hard coded activity name, when I may require to use the same thing for other purpose also. Handler is something which is dedicated to take the call. So it is better to use the things which are dedicated to particular purpose. Still will test this way, if its working fine.

Comment: Yeah so to be a little more general you would use `sendBroadcast` instead of `startActivity`, and implement a `BroadcastReceiver` for your activity. This would use an `IntentFilter` to pick out broadcasts e.g. with a particular action or category.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to start the Service with an Intent **and** bind to it. One or the other will suffice.

In this case, I would recommend binding to the Service as that gives you an opportunity to establish communication via Handlers and Messengers. You can use the onServiceConnected method of the ServiceConnection class to get a Messenger defined in the Service. See the [Android docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) under Creating a Bound Service for an example of how to do that. In their example, they return a reference to the Service instance, but you should replace that with a reference to a Messenger or Handler. Once you have a Handler/Messenger in both the Activity and the Service, it should be trivial to communicate back and forth. Note that you will probably need to call Looper.prepare() in the Thread's constructor if you put a Handler inside the background Thread.

Comment: Hey thanx for answer. Any demo or code snippet will be helpful, which demonstrate the work.

Comment: Hey I saw your code but I guess this method returns me the messanger from my service class but I need service instance as there are several other process is done via service. Is there a way that we get both the instance in my activity class

Comment: In the documentation example, it gets an instance of the Service. You can define methods in the Service to get anything you want. It sounded to me like you only needed to communicate with the Thread, so I suggested simply setting up communication with a Handler or Messenger.